# reactJS useState - how to set variables in multiple code-blocks

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, use-state

I have a reactJS component with three functional sub-components.

Function 1 declares all the state variables:

```
import React, {useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./css/TypingCarousel.css";

function TypingCarousel() {

    const [divText, setDivText] = useState("divText_default");

    const webText = ["ABC","defg","hijkl","msg4","msg5", "lastmsg"];

    {/* Get the message count */}
    const messageCount = webText.length;
    console.log("1 messageCount = [" + messageCount + "]");
    
    {/* update divText and export to App.js*/}
```

NB: If I uncomment this line I get an error "Too Many Renders"
otherwise this code works fine.

```
   {/* setDivText("abcdefg"); */}


    const elementToUpdate = <h1>{ divText }</h1>

    return(elementToUpdate);

}    

    export default TypingCarousel;
```

Further to this, what is the visibility of the state variables (and the all-important setxxx functions) to functionalcode blocks within the component?

Currently Function 2 & Function 3 sit inside Function 1.  I assumed that all the state constants & setters would then be usable by functions 2 & 3.

Would they still be usable by functions 2 & 3 if function1 was a discrete function?

One more question.  Function 3 repeatedly updates a single div.

```
       function UpdateDiv(typingElement) {  
        console.log("TypingCarousel: rendering divText"); 
        ReactDOM.render(
            <h1> { divText } </h1>,
            document.getElementById("VariableTextContainer")
        );
    }// end function UpdateDiv
```

This div is the only thing which changes in this component.  I am not sure whether to export just the function UpdateDiv or the whole 3 function module as Function App...

Comment: Please update your question with your relevant code, a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code snippet. Without it it's impossible to see what and how you are trying to update state. FYI, state updates in react are asynchronous in nature, are queued and batch processed between render cycles; i.e. the state is constant during a render cycle.

Comment: Thank you for setting me right on the set... statements.  I can work around that.

Comment: What are the 3 functions, can you include all this code and structure/organization? It still isn't clear what you are trying to do and what the issue may be. You also shouldn't need to manage the `UpdateDiv` logic yourself, the `ReactDOM.render` need only be defined once where you pass *it* your root app component, react will manage rerendering it.

Comment: Thanks mate.  I resolved that issue eventually by creating a new component and exporting/importing down the chain to Index.js for rendering.  I still have an issue with exporting the variable "divText"  but I will post that separately...